# Load BeautifulSoup output into a pandas data frame - rows unknown

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am parsing data from an HTML page.  It's in a right old mess hence I have to search through classes & spans to get my data.

I want to push the data into a data frame.

I have the code working, however, I don't know know the number of rows in advance of creating the data frame.  To test my code I set the rows to 2000.

I'd rather not loop through the HTML twice - is there a better way to build my data frame?

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, "lxml")
new_table = pd.DataFrame(columns = range(0,3), index = range(0,2000)) # I don't know the number of rows

row_marker = 0
column_marker = 0

#Column 0    
for header in soup.find_all("div", attrs={'class':'innerListing'}):
    title = header.find("h2")
    #print (title.text.strip())
    new_table.iat[row_marker,column_marker] = title.text.strip()
    row_marker +=1

column_marker = 1
row_marker = 0

#Columns 1&2
for layout in soup.find_all("div", attrs={'class':'layout'}):
    for info in layout.find_all("span", attrs={'class':'info',"id":True}):
        if "Stock" in info["id"]:
            new_table.iat[row_marker,column_marker] = info.text.strip()
            column_marker += 1
    row_marker +=1
    column_marker =1
print(new_table)
```

Comment: Where's the data coming from? Without the source, no one can actually try to solve the problem.

Comment: The data is coming from a HTML page.

Comment: That statement doesn't help. There's trillions of html pages on the internet, and maybe a couple of hundred that are actually relevant to your problem. Without a link to the html you're actually dealing with, you're wasting your time here.

Comment: I cant share the HTML page as it's private.

If we take the example code where I'm looking for H2 tags within div tags with the attribute 'InnerListing'.  

The findall returns a variable list of H2 tags depending on the time of execution - sometimes it's 100, could be 2000.   With this variable length I could find no way of determining the row count for the data frame without first looping with find all and counting the rows.  I suppose what I was looking for was soup.find_all(...).count()

Answer (score 0):

I ended up looping through the HTML in order to calculate the total rows required.